# Removing rows that contains "(null)" value from a text file

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I would like to remove any row within a .txt file that contains "(null)". The (null) value is always in the 3rd column. I would like to add this to a script that I already have.

Txt file example:

```
39|1411|XXYZ
40|1416|XXX
41|1420|(null)
```

In this example I would like to remove the third row.
Im guessing its an awk -F but not sure from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track with using `-F`.

```
$ awk -F '|' '$3 != "(null)"' file.txt
39|1411|XXYZ
40|1416|XXX
```

You set the field separator to `|`, then print all lines where the third field is not equal to `(null)`. This uses awk's default of "print the line" if there's no action associated with a pattern.

If you relax the requirement to specifically test the third field, and there is no other place for the "(null)" substring to occur, you can get the same result with

```
grep -vF '(null)' file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. I went with the ```grep -vF '(null)' file.txt``` because of its succinctness.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '-F|' '$3 != "(null)"' <  input-file
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `sed`:

```
$ sed '/(null)$/d' file
39|1411|XXYZ
40|1416|XXX
```

The `$` assures that the `(null)` is at the end of the line. If you want to assure that `(null)` is the final column:

```
$ sed '/\|(null)$/d' file
```

And if you want to be *extra sure* that it is the third column:

```
$ sed '/^[^|]*\|[^|]*\|(null)$/d' file
```

Or with `grep`:

```
$ grep -v '^[^|]*|[^|]*|(null)$'
```

(But instead of this last one, just use `awk`...)

Answer (score 1):

**Use `grep`:**

```
grep -v '|.*|(null)' in_file
```

Here, [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses option `-v` : print lines that do **not** match.

**Or use Perl:**

```
perl -F'[|]' -lane 'print if $F[2] ne "(null)";' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F'[|]'` : Split into `@F` on literal `|`, rather than on whitespace.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: Note that `-P` for perl patterns is not a POSIX grep option.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you for the suggestion to use `grep` without the `-P` option. Updated the answer.

Comment: More specific with anchors: `grep -v '^[^|]*|[^|]*|(null)$'`

Answer (score 1):

*I would like to remove any row within a .txt file that contains "(null)"*

If you wish to do that using `AWK` let `file.txt` content be

```
39|1411|XXYZ
40|1416|XXX
41|1420|(null)
```

then

```
awk '!index($0,"(null)")' file.txt
```

will output

```
39|1411|XXYZ
40|1416|XXX
```

Explanation: `index` return position of first occurence of substring (`(null)` in this case) or 0 if none will find, I negate what is return thus getting truth for 0 and false for anything else and AWK does print where result was truth.